# Prove Logical Equivalence

Tags: logic

I've been stuck on this one problem for a couple of days now with no clue on how to complete it. I need to prove the following logical equivalence:

(¬P ∧ ¬R) ∨ (P ∧ ¬Q ∧ ¬R) is equivalent to ¬R ∧ (Q ⇒ ¬(P ∧ ¬R))

If anyone could shed some light on this matter, please..

Comment: Try distributing and using the fact that $P\implies Q\iff \sim P \vee Q$.

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: the above and you only have 3 variables so you can just use a truth table.  if not that show each implies the other/simplify by laws of logic.  should be $\neg P\vee Q$

Comment: Paraphrasing ncmathsadist's comment: you can use the fact that $A \to B$ is equivalent to $\neg A \vee B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working first on the left hand expression gives

$$\begin{align}
(\lnot P\land\lnot R)\lor(P\land\lnot Q\land\lnot R)
&=\lnot R\land(\lnot P\lor(P\land\lnot Q))\\
&=\lnot R\land((\lnot P\lor P)\land(\lnot P\lor\lnot Q))\\
&=\lnot R\land(\lnot P\lor\lnot Q)
\end{align}$$

Working next on the right hand expression gives

$$\begin{align}
\lnot R\land(Q\implies\lnot(P\land\lnot R))
&=\lnot R\land(\lnot Q\lor\lnot(P\land\lnot R))\\
&=\lnot R\land(\lnot Q\lor\lnot P\lor R)\\
&=(\lnot R\land(\lnot Q\lor \lnot P))\lor(\lnot R\land R)\\
&=\lnot R\land(\lnot Q\lor \lnot P)
\end{align}$$